# Predicting thrust of a Motor

Tags: motors, aerospace-engineering, propulsion

I want to be able to predict the load a single motor and propeller can carry, so I can choose an appropriately sized propeller and powerful enough motor.

I say predict because I'm first going to observe the effects of varying diameter and RPM with a smaller less powerful motor, and once that is complete, I can use the information to get a more powerful motor (and bigger propeller), aiming for thrust force of about 30-50kgf.

I'll be using a tachometer to measure the RPM, a potentiometer to vary the voltage and a (taped down) kitchen scale to measure the thrust force. I plan to power on the motor while on the scale and see how the mass reading decreases, and use that to calculate the force. Is that an appropriate method? Or should I try another way?

Comment: What props are you looking at? APC provides data.

Comment: See additions about rough relationships.

Comment: I've checked out APC, thanks for the reference, they have useful data. I'll try to derive something from it and will probably make another post after I've reached another inevitable problem :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless have really good data for the propeller, motor, and airframe then you cannot "calculate".

Propeller thrust depends on the the RPM, and speed that the propeller is moving through the air. That is a 3-axis graph right there.

Motor speed depends the torque which is a two-axis graph. If the voltage is not fixed then it becomes another 3-axis graph.

And airspeed depends on the speed that the airframe is moving through the air and the drag of the airframe which is a two-axis graph.

So the thrust is determined by an intersection of two 3-axis graphs and one 2-axis graph. It's a big interwined ball of numbers. Not to mention that to calculate any of it from the shape of the propeller or the design of the motor is impractical unless you are a design engineer with really good data and simulation software for those parts.

Your best bet is to use propeller data tables that list the torque and thrust and different combinations of RPM and slipstream speeds.

Then use that with motor torque-speed curves. If you have gearing available then that adds some more degrees of freedom since you now have to adjust the gear ratio so that for each propeller you operate at the motor's maximum power point or maximum efficiency point.

And then estimate the drag of your airframe at various speeds (probably by some rudimentary drag equations and gut feel).

APC Propellers provides data for their propellers under "Technical Data".

---

You did not say how the propeller is being used but you do say "maximize the weight it can support" or "carry weight" which I assume means this is being used to hover like a helicopter. In that case it gets a little bit simpler because your airspeed is zero (since you are hovering) which means your airframe drag is also pretty much zero. So that cuts out 1/3 of your work.

That allows for a less technical approach:

Calculate the no-load RPM of your motor at the desired operating voltage. Most DC motors have peak efficiency of about 70-80% of their no-load speed (about 1/7th of their stall-torque). So hunt around different propeller data tables until you find a good thrust value at zero slip stream speed (since you are just hovering) at your 70-80% of your motor's no-load RPM where the listed propeller input also does not exceed that of the motor. For hovering, you want largest diameter propeller and for a fixed motor power, that will mean the propeller with the lowest pitch. So what you should do is make a list of the lowest pitch propeller available for each diameter. Then run through the data tables for each propeller in order until you find the largest one that won't burn out your motor.

---

You can kind of use rules of thumb relationships, all other things equal (things like diameter, pitch, airspeed, RPM, blade number, and prop geometry. APC blades are basically all the same airfoil within a line: gas, electric, slow flyer), to extrapolate from a few data points like:

- Motor RPM is proportional to Voltage
- Motor torque  is proportional to current
- Propeller torque is proportional to RPM squared (as per NASA drag equation)
- Propeller thrust is proportional to RPM squared (I think, as per NASA lift equation)
- Propeller airspeed proportional to RPM

Those are the generic well known ones.

There are also a very crudes for one propeller thrust and torque as diameter or pitch vary. I forget them though. I think the only one I looked at was diameter vs torque and diameter vs thrust. I think they were proportional to diameter squared (i.e. prop disc area). You can find them by staring at the APC data with a calculator and trial and error.

I hesitate to combine multiple relations though due to the error. I only ever moved between a single parameter. At least you can ignore varying airspeed.